# Is there a way to measure a netcore webAPI server (Krestel) start-up time?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, app-startup

I need to document the startup/shutdown time of my self-hosted WebAPI server. This is required as there are lot of configuration file readings going on during startup.
I couldn't find any way to measure this as the it somewhere happens inside this usually:

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Can I add any profilers, performance log within the app so as to get the required performance data? Or else, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Any logger library or resharper dottrace tools can be used

Comment: Thanks for the comment @VimalCK. I am not allowed to use any third-party libraries or tools as such. Will try with microsoft console logger?

Comment: You can use console logger or logging to a file according to your needs